# Not able to add workflow display name in the business process flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

While creating this business process flow and adding the workflow to the global I am not able to edit the display name.
[image]

Comment: Can you try different browser?

Comment: @ArunVinoth Yes tried Chrome and Edge but still it doesn't work